# Indexing ACL ManifoldCF + ElasticSearch + CMIS

Tags: elasticsearch, alfresco, cmis, manifoldcf

I need to index ACL in Elastic Search using ManifoldCF and CMIS connector.
I have added CMIS authority connector with params:

```
Name:   EVERYONE_AUTHORITY  Description:    
Authority type: CMISAuthorityConnector  Max connections:    10
Authority group:    GROUP_EVERYONE  Authorization domain:   
Prerequisite user mapping:  UserMappingConnection
Parameters: repositoryId=-default-
endpoint=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

But ACL is not indexed in documents I have got something like this:

```
"allow_token_document" : "__nosecurity__","deny_token_document" : "__nosecurity__","allow_token_share" : "__nosecurity__","deny_token_share" : "__nosecurity__","allow_token_parent" : "__nosecurity__","deny_token_parent" : "__nosecurity__"
```

Help me please.

Comment: why do you want to use CMIS authentication connector? does elastic search expose any cmis services?

Comment: I want to use CMIS authentication connector to be able to index ACL retreived from CMIS.

Comment: In Manifold Authentication and Repository connectors operate on differently, that is, Repository connector does not consult authentication connector to index permission for the document. if you are to index ACL of a document you much do so explicitly in repository connector.